# i need my methods DrawBall to intersect with DrawBat so that the ball bounces off the bat?

Tags: c#, .net

i need to somehow use my DrawBall method to intersect with DrawBat so that when the ball hits the bat it deflects using the intersect method. How can i declare my methods to a type where it will allow to do this??

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Graphics paper;
    private SolidBrush brush, brushBlue, brushGreen, brushRed,
                       brushBlk, brushYellow;

    private int x, y, xDirection, yDirection, xBat;
    private int playCount, brushSize, ball;
    private Random randomNumber;
    private bool btnDisplayBricksClicked;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        paper = picBox.CreateGraphics();
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        brushBlue = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        brushGreen = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        brushRed = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        brushBlk = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        brushYellow = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);

        randomNumber = new Random();
        btnDisplayBricksClicked = false;

        ball =  DrawBall();                 //need help here error: cannot implicitly convert void to int




    }

    private void MoveBall()
    {
        timer1.Interval = randomNumber.Next(50, 100);
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        x = x + xDirection;
        y = y + yDirection;

        if (x >= picBox.Width)
            xDirection = -xDirection;

        if (y >= picBox.Height)
            yDirection = -yDirection;

        if (x <= 0)
            xDirection = -xDirection;

        if (y <= 0)
            yDirection = -yDirection;
    }

    private void DrawBall()
    {
        brushSize = 15;
        paper.FillEllipse(brush, x, y, brushSize, brushSize);
    }

    private void DrawBricks(Graphics paper)
    {
        int xPos = 25;
        int yPos = 25;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 20;

        paper.FillRectangle(brushBlue, xPos, yPos, width, height);
        paper.FillRectangle(brushGreen, xPos + 110, yPos, width, height);
        paper.FillRectangle(brushRed, xPos + 220, yPos, width, height);
        paper.FillRectangle(brushBlk, xPos + 330, yPos, width, height);
        paper.FillRectangle(brushYellow, xPos + 440, yPos, width, height);
    }

    private void DrawBat(Graphics paper)
    {

        paper.FillRectangle(brushBlue, xBat - 25, picBox.Height - 20, 50, 10);
    }

    private void CheckCollision()
    {


    }

    private void picBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        xBat = e.X;
    }

    private void btnLaunchRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playCount == 0)
        {
            paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert £1 to play, You have no credit");
            return;
        }

        playCount--;

        x = randomNumber.Next(20, 300);
        y = randomNumber.Next(0, picBox.Height / 2);
        xDirection = randomNumber.Next(5, 20);
        yDirection = randomNumber.Next(5, 20);

        MoveBall();
    }

    private void btnInsertCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);
        playCount = 5;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);

        DrawBall();

        MoveBall();

        DrawBat(paper);

        if (btnDisplayBricksClicked)
        {
            DrawBricks(paper);
        }          

    }

    private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playCount == 0)
        {
            paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert £1 to play, You have no credit");
            return;
        }

        playCount--;

        x = picBox.Width / 2;
        y = picBox.Height / 2;
        xDirection = randomNumber.Next(5, 20) - 21;
        yDirection = 1;

        MoveBall();

    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playCount == 0)
        {
            paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert £1 to play, You have no credit");
            return;
        }

        playCount--;

        x = picBox.Width / 2;
        y = picBox.Height / 2;
        xDirection = randomNumber.Next(5, 10) + 15;
        yDirection = 1;

        MoveBall();
    }

    private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playCount == 0)
        {
            paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert £1 to play, You have no credit");
            return;
        }

        playCount--;

        x = picBox.Width / 2;
        y = picBox.Height / 2;
        xDirection = 1;
        yDirection = randomNumber.Next(5, 20) - 21;

        MoveBall();
    }

    private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playCount == 0)
        {
            paper.Clear(Color.LightSteelBlue);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert £1 to play, You have no credit");
            return;
        }

        playCount--;

        x = picBox.Width / 2;
        y = picBox.Height / 2;
        xDirection = 1;
        yDirection = randomNumber.Next(1, 5) + 6;

        MoveBall();
    }

    private void btnDisplayBricks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnDisplayBricksClicked = true;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "DrawBall method to intersect with DrawBat"? Can you explain more?

Comment: Maybe some more code to help us help you?  I don't normally like to look through a lot of code on here, but this one sounds interesting enough to me.

Comment: i am working on a project where i can only use a pictureBox as the paper (NOT ALLOWED PAINT EVENT), so what i have done is drawn the ball and bat in separate methods that effectively draws them objects in the pictureBox. i need to get the ball to intersect with the bat but because there in methods(WHICH IS REQUIRED) how do i make it possible to intersect the two methods? do i have to delegate each method to some type? or is there another way of doing this??

Comment: *ball = DrawBall(); //need help here error: cannot implicitly convert void to int*  This means that ball is declared as type int, and you can't convert a void to an int.  DrawBall() is a void and can't be assigned to a variable.

Comment: What is `ball` even supposed to be here? You've defined it as an `int` and then tried to assign the result of a function (`DrawBall`) that has a return type of `void`.

Comment: But figuring out if a rectangle (the bat) overlaps with a circle (the ball) should be relatively trivial. If you know the center of the circle and it's radius, you should be able to check if the edges of the rectangle overlap with some simple math.

Comment: i was trying to set method DrawBall to ball so then i could use ball to intersect with bat(i was also going to do the same with the bat) am i wronf in thinking this would work?

Comment: What exactly would the integer returned from `DrawBall` even contain?

Comment: would it have to be ballRectangle = new Rectangle then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm going to have to work on this a little longer and won't be able to post the full answer until tomorrow or late tonight, but to get you started... Think "Objects" instead of methods.

For instance, your Ball is an object (class), and your Bat is an object (class).

```
    private Ball ball = new Ball();
    private Bat bat = new Bat();

    public class Ball : Form1
    {
        public int Xpos { get; set; }
        public int Ypos { get; set; }

        public void Draw()
        {
            brushSize = 15;
            paper.FillEllipse(brush, Xpos, Ypos, brushSize, brushSize);
        }
        public void Move(int xDir, int yDir)
        {
            timer1.Interval = randomNumber.Next(50, 100);
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            Xpos = Xpos + xDir;
            Ypos = Ypos + yDir;

            if (x >= picBox.Width)
                xDir = -xDir;

            if (y >= picBox.Height)
                yDir = -yDir;

            if (x <= 0)
                xDir = -xDir;

            if (y <= 0)
                yDir = -yDir;
        }
    }

    public class Bat : Form1
    {
        public int Xpos { get; set; }
        public int Ypos { get; set; }

        public void Draw()
        {
            paper.FillRectangle(brushBlue, xBat - 25, picBox.Height - 20, 50, 10);
        }
    }
```

Once you create your objects (classes), then you can start creating the actions (methods) that those objects can perform.  For this quick example, I mostly used the methods that you already had in place and changed how they are called.  For instance, now if you want to draw your ball and make your ball move, you would do this:

```
        ball.Draw();
        ball.Move(x, y);
```

This way you are calling the action on the object itself.  At any point in time, you could check the position of the ball object like this:

```
        int ballXpos = ball.Xpos;
        int ballYpos = ball.Ypos;
```

You could then compare this information to similar information you have about your bat object, and then action upon this information from there.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started on the right track.  I may be on later tonight to finish this up for you, otherwise, I can have the solution to this problem finished tomorrow.  Please let me know if you have any questions at all.

Comment: thank you for your time no rush in the solution but i understand your ideas which sounds good, if you don't mind continuing to help that would be great thanks again